# Bash check if script is running with exact options

Tags: bash, pid

I know how to check if a script is already running (`if pidof -o %PPID -x "scriptname.sh"; then...`). But now I have a script that accepts inputs as flags, so it can be used in several different scenarios, many of which will probably run at the same time.

Example:

`/opt/scripts/backup/tar.sh -d /directory1 -b /backup/dir -c /config/dir`

and

`/opt/scripts/backup/tar.sh -d /directory2 -b /backup/dir -c /config/dir`

The above runs a backup script that I wrote, and the flags are the parameters for the script: the directory being backed up, the backup location, and the configuration location. The above example are two different backups (`directory 1` and `directory 2`) and therefore should be allowed to run simultaneously.

*Is there any way for a script to check if it is being run **and** check if the running version is using the exact same parameters/flags?*

Comment: You could compare the arguments of your script , `$@`, with the output of the command: `ps -hfo cmd $(pidof "$(basename $0)")`

Answer (score 1):

The `ps -Af` command will provide you all the processes that run on you os with the "command" line used to run them.

Answer (score 0):

One solution :

```
if ps auxwww | grep '/[o]pt/scripts/backup/tar.*/directory2'; then
    echo "running"
else
    echo "NOT running"
fi
```

Comment: what is the `auxwww`. I've never seen it before.